# changing the wordpress gallery image size default

Tags: wordpress

I was wondering if any could help on my problem

I have this code from someone that runs fine except that the size does not function, default is always on "thumbnail"

```
function my_gallery_default_type_set_link( $settings ) {
    $settings['galleryDefaults']['link'] = 'file';
    $settings['galleryDefaults']['columns'] = '4';
    $settings['galleryDefaults']['size'] = 'large';
    return $settings;
}
add_filter( 'media_view_settings', 'my_gallery_default_type_set_link');
```

how can I make this always in large as a default?

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code is actually working, the size of the gallery will be "large" by default if an other size is not manually selected. The real problem come from the dropdown itself that is not correctly set on initialisation, still in WP 4.8.2.

There is a [ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/40692) open with more details about this display error.

In the meantime, I found a workaround using the print_media_templates hook :

Step 1 - Define your gallery default image size

```
function my_gallery_default_settings( $settings ) {
    $settings['galleryDefaults']['size'] = 'large';
    return $settings;
}
add_filter( 'media_view_settings', 'my_gallery_default_settings');
```

Step 2 - Debug the dropdown image size default value

```
function debug_gallery_image_size_default_value() {
  ?>

  <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      wp.media.view.Settings.Gallery = wp.media.view.Settings.Gallery.extend({
        template: function(view){
          var base_view = wp.media.template('gallery-settings')(view);
          var size_option_search = '<option value="'+wp.media.gallery.defaults.size+'">';
          var size_option_replace = '<option value="'+wp.media.gallery.defaults.size+'" selected="selected">';
          base_view = base_view.replace(size_option_search, size_option_replace);
          return base_view;
        }
      });
    });
  </script>

  <?php
}
add_action('print_media_templates', 'debug_gallery_image_size_default_value');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using someone else's custom code? There is already a Gallery shortcode with size option in it:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode

Just call it with `[gallery size="thumbnail"]`.

Comment: I need it all to be in default state since its for a wordpress mobile app., I think you cannot edit any in the gallery on wordpress mobile app

Comment: Is there a difference between making a content with wordpress mobile app, and regular wp site?

Comment: there is a difference, on the edit gallery you cannot specify image size, only number of columns, you can set the size if you go the its HTML interface and add link="file", size="large" which will make users don't want to post

Answer (score 0):

Actually, other code in other answers replaces default settings for existing galleries. Here's the code to apply default settings only to the new gallery:

```
add_filter( 'media_view_settings', 'theme_gallery_defaults', 10, 2 );

function theme_gallery_defaults( $settings, $post ) {
    $defaults = ! empty( $settings['galleryDefaults'] ) && is_array( $settings['galleryDefaults'] ) ? $settings['galleryDefaults'] : array();
    $settings['galleryDefaults'] = array_merge( $defaults, array(
        'columns'   => 5,
        'size'      => 'large',
        'link'      => 'file'
    ) );
    return $settings;
}
```